# How to shorten list of syntax options in Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Using Sublime Text 3, is there a way to shorten the list of syntax options that are presented when changing the syntax? There are about 50 language options, and I only use about 5, so I'd like to only see those 5 to quickly select, .e.g., css, js, html, php, or sql.

I imagine there's a way to do this without deleting the syntax files, rather some kind of user settings override.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable a lot of syntaxes by disabling it's package with Package Control.

- `Ctrl + shift + P`
- type `disable`, and select "Package Control: Disable Package"
- Find syntax's package and select it.

Comment: Perfect. I was also able to re-enable using the same steps above with `enable`.

Answer (score 9):

Using @d_rail's advice, I disabled the packages. That resulted in the following settings in my User preferences file:

```
{
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "ActionScript",
        "C++",
        "Haskell",
        "TCL",
        "Go",
        "Lisp",
        "Graphviz",
        "Scala",
        "Pascal",
        "Clojure",
        "ASP",
        "Vintage",
        "Objective-C",
        "R",
        "RestructuredText",
        "Erlang",
        "Groovy",
        "Lua",
        "OCaml",
        "C#",
        "Matlab",
        "Textile",
        "D",
        "Batch File",
        "AppleScript",
        "Makefile",
        "LaTeX",
        "Java"
    ]
}
```

Comment: IMO much more convenient option than @d_rail's one

Comment: How can we disable a sub-package? For example... I want to keep C# but remove "NAnt Build File" which lives under the C# entry in the UI syntax list?  I have tried "C#\\NAnt Build File" and variations on that... with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unwanted syntax files from the Sublime packages directory.

Comment: I tried removing the syntax files, but that didn't work for me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Know of a way to do this via User settings?

Comment: Just asking... are you sure you removed them from the correct folder? I don't know your platform, but removing the syntax files really should be all that is needed. If it is Windows, it will be under AppData.

Comment: Nope, I am not sure. But I removed all instances of the "Haskell" syntax file I could find on my system. Using OSX and Sublime Text 3.